# Multi-field, multi-type search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 types `Author` and `Book`.  I want to search both types and return matches from the fields `Author.name` and `Book.title`.  How would I complete this query?

`GET /bookstore/author,book/_search` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches based on what you're trying to accomplish.

1. You could model your data so that you
   store indexed values for the author in the book type, and possibly a
   reference to that author.
2. Otherwise you should be able to query 2 types, however you cannot
   specify which value to search for in which type. These would
   technically be 2 separate queries, and you'd have to mix the 2
   results yourself if this is what you desire.

It is possible to search both given that book doesn't have an attribute "name", and author doesn't have an attribute "title". If you search for a field that doesn't exist elasticsearch will still try given that the data in the model is schema-less, and a mapping simply defines how to index fields but doesn't necessarily define the structure of the documents.

If you're trying to make a single search for both book and author then I'd recommend doing 2 separate queries, as you'll get 2 separate types of documents which may need to be treated accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a query to the index, not only the type: /yourindex/_search.

Now, you should use a multi match query to control your results better:

```
{ 
    "multi_match" : { 
        "query": "Will Smith", "fields": [
            "type1.title", "type2.name" 
        ]  
    } 
}
```

More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html